# Getting the gradients and feature map of a pre trained model

Tags: pytorch, gradient, feature-extraction, pre-trained-model

Is there a way to get the gradient values and feature maps for each layer (in pytorch) of a model that's already been trained?

I'm working with hugging faces UNet model and I'm trying to get the weights and feature mpa for each layer, but I can't think of any way of doing that that doesn't included retraining the model.